# Removing an app completely not installed by apt-get

Tags: f.lux

I have installed an app by going on a bit of a rampage trying different things, and in the end I'm not completely sure what I did. But I do know that something is installed and I want to remove it.

The app is fluxgui. I installed it on 16.04 ubuntu right now after it was released and I was unable to install xflux with it. trying to remove it with apt-get says package not found, and I think I may have installed it from source.

I know it's there because the app has a gui that starts up when I start the OS.
I did a locate and found the following:

```
katana@katana:~$ locate flux
/home/katana/.config/autostart/fluxgui.desktop
/home/katana/.gconf/apps/fluxgui
/home/katana/.gconf/apps/fluxgui/%gconf.xml
/home/katana/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/F889_flux.0.png
/home/katana/.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/F889_flux.0.png
/home/katana/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/F889_flux.0.png
/home/katana/.wine/drive_c/users/katana/Local Settings/Application Data/FluxSoftware/Flux/flux.exe
/home/katana/.wine/drive_c/users/katana/Local Settings/Application Data/FluxSoftware/Flux/runtime/flux.psd
/home/katana/.wine/drive_c/users/katana/Local Settings/Application Data/FluxSoftware/Flux/runtime/flux.tre
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/fluxgui
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/fluxgui-dark.svg
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/fluxgui-light.svg
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/fluxgui.svg
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/xflux
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/xflux32
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/__init__.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/exceptions.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/fluxapp.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/fluxcontroller.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/preferences.glade
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/settings.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/fluxgui/xfluxcontroller.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/build/scripts-2.7/fluxgui
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/desktop/fluxgui.desktop
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/__init__.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/exceptions.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/fluxapp.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/fluxcontroller.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/preferences.glade
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/settings.py
/home/katana/workspace/f.lux-indicator-applet/src/fluxgui/xfluxcontroller.py
/usr/local/bin/fluxgui
/usr/local/bin/xflux
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/exceptions.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/exceptions.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxcontroller.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxcontroller.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/preferences.glade
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/settings.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/settings.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/xfluxcontroller.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/xfluxcontroller.pyc
/usr/local/share/applications/fluxgui.desktop
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/fluxgui-dark.svg
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/fluxgui-light.svg
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/fluxgui.svg
```

I'm sure if I just remove the entry from autostart it will stop launching, but I'd like to have it all removed. I'm thinking I can just delete all the files in lib, bin, and share, but I'm afraid I'll leave some hidden config files or something. Any advice?

Edit:
I see xflux is there, but it is only installed in user space, and not for root. It requires root, but when I try to run it as root it can't find it.

Comment: Do you still have the source where you compiled it from? You can generally cd into the source and run `make uninstall`.

Comment: The repo just has a python script to install, there's no target to make uninstall it seems. https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui

Comment: And I'm not even sure if I did install from source, because when I try to run setup.py I get the following trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    rename("xflux64", "xflux")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you may have a version of fluxgui running in WINE. If it would not be too disruptive, you could try uninstalling WINE and seeing if that helped get rid of fluxgui. Then, when the coast is clear, you could reinstall WINE.

The most important files I'm seeing from what you posted:

```
/home/katana/.config/autostart/fluxgui.desktop
# launcher for the binary  

/home/katana/.wine/drive_c/users/katana/Local Settings/Application Data/FluxSoftware/Flux/flux.exe
# without the .exe the app cannot run

/usr/local/bin/fluxgui
# this is where Ubuntu looks to run your program. again the app cannot run without its binary.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui
# This is interesting. This tells me that fluxgui is a Python package.
# You could try using pip to uninstall:
# pip uninstall fluxgui

/usr/local/share/applications/fluxgui.desktop
# again, another launcher shortcut to the binary. remove this, and the app will be difficult to run.
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem to be honest. The Wine things is unrelated and can be ignored. Basically I want to be able to remove all of the native linux flux stuff, and as I've mentioned I think I can removed it all by just deleting all the files that are non-wine, but I'm afraid there are some config files or sth that will be left behind.

Comment: Did you try the pip uninstall?